# Array cannot be indexed by RangeFull?

Tags: rust, traits

Consider the following example:

```rust
use std::ops::Index;
use std::ops::RangeFull;

fn f<T: Index<RangeFull>>(x: T) {}

fn main() {
    let x: [i32; 4] = [0, 1, 2, 3];
    f(x);
}
```

Upon calling `f(x)`, I get an error:

```
error[E0277]: the type `[i32; 4]` cannot be indexed by `std::ops::RangeFull`
 --> src/main.rs:8:5
  |
8 |     f(x);
  |     ^ `[i32; 4]` cannot be indexed by `std::ops::RangeFull`
  |
  = help: the trait `std::ops::Index<std::ops::RangeFull>` is not implemented for `[i32; 4]`
note: required by `f`
 --> src/main.rs:4:1
  |
4 | fn f<T: Index<RangeFull>>(x: T) {}
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I am confused. I can obviously write, for example, `let y = x[..];`. Does this not mean indexing `x` with `RangeFull`? Are arrays somehow special in this regard?

Comment: Because it's implemented for `[T]` not `[T; 4]`, that is still not possible maybe in the future it will compile, You need to do https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=206910f2f763864a273f58013c5f7c71. Can't help you more.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the [documentation for the primitive array type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html), `Index<…>` is not directly implemented for arrays. This is partly because it would currently be impossible to provide blanket implementations for all array sizes, but mainly because it's not necessary; the implementation for slices is sufficient for most purposes.

The expression `x[..]` is translated to `*std::ops::Index::index(&x, ..)` by the compiler, which in turn is evaluated according to the [usual method call semantics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html). Since there is no implementation of `Index<RangeFull>` for arrays, the compiler repeatedly dereferences `&x` and performs an unsized coercion at the end, eventually finding the implementation of `Index<RangeFull>` for `[i32]`.

The process of calling a generic function, like `f()` in your example, is different from method call semantics. The compiler first infers what `T` is based on the argument you are passing; in this case `T` is inferred to be `[i32; 4]`. In the next step, the compiler verifies whether `T` satisfies the trait bounds, and since it doesn't, you get an error message.

If we want to make your code work, we need to make sure to pass a slice to `f()`. Since a slice is unsized, we need to pass it by reference, so we need to define `f()` like this:

```
fn f<T: ?Sized + Index<RangeFull>>(_: &T) {}
```

The `?Sized` is necessary since type parameters receive an implicit `Sized` bound. When calling `f()`, we need to make sure `T` is actually inferred as `[i32]` rather than `[i32; 4]`. To this end, we can either explicitly specify `T`

```
f::<[_]>(&x);
```

or explicitly perform the unsized conversion before passing the argument, so the compiler infers the desired type:

```
f(&x as &[_]);
f(&x[..])
```