# &[u8] cannot be indexed by RangeFull?

Tags: rust, traits

I am trying to create a struct which can contain anything that is sliceable to `[u8]`.

```
use std::ops::{Index, RangeFull};

struct Wrapper<DataT>
where
    DataT: ?Sized + Index<RangeFull, Output = [u8]>, 
{
    data: DataT,
}

impl<DataT> Wrapper<DataT>
where
    DataT: ?Sized + Index<RangeFull, Output = [u8]>, 
{
    
    fn subwrapper(&self) -> Wrapper<Vec<u8>> {
        let mut buffer = Vec::<u8>::new();
        buffer.extend_from_slice(&self.data[..]);
        Wrapper {
            data: buffer,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let data : [u8; 3] = [1, 2, 3];
    let w = Wrapper {data: &data[..]};
    let sub = w.subwrapper();
}
```

I get the error

```
error[E0277]: the type `&[u8]` cannot be indexed by `std::ops::RangeFull`
  --> src/main.rs:24:13
   |
3  | / struct Wrapper<DataT>
4  | | where
5  | |     DataT: ?Sized + Index<RangeFull, Output = [u8]>, {
6  | |         data: DataT,
7  | |     }
   | |_____- required by `Wrapper`
...
24 |       let w = Wrapper {data: &data[..]};
   |               ^^^^^^^ `&[u8]` cannot be indexed by `std::ops::RangeFull`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::ops::Index<std::ops::RangeFull>` is not implemented for `&[u8]`
```

I followed [Array cannot be indexed by RangeFull?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55925523/array-cannot-be-indexed-by-rangefull), but it didn't seem to solve the issue. Is this because `&[u8]` is a slice? When I try using the `SliceIndex` trait it seems to break for the `Vec`. Is there a way to say either trait is acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that while a slice `[u8]` implements `Index<RangeFull>`, a reference to a slice `&[u8]` does not. And it is the reference that you're trying to store in `Wrapper` so `DataT` is inferred to be `&[u8]`, thus the trait bound `DataT: Index<FullRange>` is not satisfied.

If your goal is to cover "anything that's sliceable to `[u8]`", you should likely use other traits, though. A trait like `AsRef<[u8]>` might be better here, as it indicates "a reference to this type can be converted into a reference of  a slice `[u8]`", which might be a more suitable definition of "sliceable to `[u8]`". (Other traits like `Deref<Target = [u8]>` might also be suitable alterantives here.)

Using `AsRef`, your code would become:

```rust
struct Wrapper<DataT>
where
    DataT: AsRef<[u8]>, // <-- new trait bound
{
    data: DataT,
}

impl<DataT> Wrapper<DataT>
where
    DataT: AsRef<[u8]>, // <-- new trait bound
{
    fn subwrapper(&self) -> Wrapper<Vec<u8>> {
        let buffer = self.data.as_ref() // <-- use `.as_ref()` to get `&[u8]`
            .to_vec();                  // <-- more efficient way to get `Vec<u8>`
                                        //       from `&[u8]`
        Wrapper { data: buffer }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let data: [u8; 3] = [1, 2, 3];
    let w = Wrapper { data: &data }; // <-- no need to use `[..]` here, as
                                     //       `[u8; N]` implements `AsRef<[u8]>`
    let sub = w.subwrapper();
}
```

[Playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9a1f91b87d6d02b8cde66200a1c2d386)